# Check if an integer is GCD of some elements in a given set

Tags: algorithm, math, greatest-common-divisor

Given a set of positive integers and an integer `k`. **All of the elements** in the set is divisible by `k`.

How to check if `k` is greatest common divisor of **some** elements in the set?

My idea: For every element `a[i]` in the set, I divide it by `k`. Then I get GCD of all of the element in the set (which was changed after I divided). If the GCD is equal to 1, then `k` is GCD of some elements in the set.

I have make some test cases and I see it right. But the online judge doesn't accept. Please give me an idea, or check my algorithm and fix it. Thank you very much.

Let me speak it more clearly:

For instance, a = {10, 15, 18}:

`k = 5` is GCD(10, 15). Answer is `true`

`k = 3` is GCD(15, 18). Answer is `true`

`k = 1` is GCD(10, 15, 18). Answer is `true`

`k = 6` is not GCD of any group which contains more than 2 integers. Answer is `false`

Size of the set: <= 100000

EDIT: Sorry for giving a wrong example. It was my mistake. `k = 3` is not GCD(10, 18). But I thought you might know this is `15` instead, right. :) Thanks for your answers, comments and contribution. I have voted an accepted answer below.

Comment: @Paulo: Actually, this is a small thing in my another problem which I have asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471157/algorithm-gcd-and-lcm-problems). So I just want to check if this idea is true. :)

Comment: See if my code fits into what you want.

Comment: i have updated an example. Please review. :)

Comment: Ok, now I see that you want any group of two values in the array. Is that right? If so, I can give you another answer.

Comment: group of **more than two integers**. I used the word "some". :D Thanks for your enthusiasm. And please note that the size of set maybe over 10^5.

Comment: Over? Or until 10^5?

Comment: its 10^5, but you have to process on at most 5 test cases like that. :)

Comment: I've posted the solution, can you see it?

Comment: wait, i'll type the answer..

Comment: "k=3 is GCD(10, 18)" ???  3 is not a divisor of 10, much less a greatest common divisor.....

Comment: Hoang cannot write question

Comment: my mistake, GCD (15, 18). Did you get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 the question is incoherent with the example:**

for 10, 15, 18:

- 3 is not a divisor of 10, neither 6
- there is no common divisor

**2 your question can be reduced like that :**

- k divides every elements, so divide them => new "reduced" set
- if k was GCD of some subset, then, the corresponding reduced subset has 1 as GCD (they are prime together)
- so we can forget k

**3 the problem is now: given a set, is it a subset of elements prime together (or with 1 as GCD) ?**

but if it is true from a subset, it is true for all elements.

So **your** algorithm is good: take A1, A2, and GCD, then GCD of this an A3, ...

If at some point you get 1, it is finished.

Comment: Further more, I have done as you said before I asked this question. But if this is an accepted solution, I wouldn't have to ask. Anyway, I'm glad that you agree with me. I will try harder. And sorry again for my mistake in the question. I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
  int c;
  while(a != 0) {
     c = a;
     a = b%a;
     b = c;
  }
  return b;
}

bool function(int[] a, int n, int k) {
    int numberOfGCD = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
            if(gcd(a[i], a[j]) == k) numberOfGCD++;
    return numberOfGCD > 1;
}
```